# Insert variable as pandas iloc function parameter

Tags: python, pandas

I want to insert iloc parameter using variable

```
attribute_name = ['CP_ST', 'CP_ES', 'CP_AD', 'CP_ININ', 'CP_IMIN', 'CP_CL', 'CP_CF', 'CP_SM', 'CP_TL', 'CP_COV']
indices = 1
list_of_attr = ""
for str in attribute_name :
    if(indices != len(attribute_name)):
        list_of_attr += "'" + str + "'"
        list_of_attr += ","
        indices +=1
    else:
        list_of_attr += "'" + str + "'"
        indices +=1

hope_df = hope_df.loc[ : , [list_of_attr] ]
```

I want to pass "list_of_attr" to iloc function

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, could you show and example of your dataframe and your expected output?

Answer (score 2):

You should pass your attribute names in a list directly:

```
attribute_name = ['CP_ST', 'CP_ES', 'CP_AD', 'CP_ININ', 'CP_IMIN', 'CP_CL', 'CP_CF', 'CP_SM', 'CP_TL', 'CP_COV']

hope_df = hope_df.loc[ : , attribute_name ]
```